# Wrapping a HTML5 app into an executable for Windows/Linux/Mac

Tags: html, cross-platform, executable

I'm building a HTML5 mobile app which I'm going to wrap in an Android and an iOS app with a simple web view. However, I have some users that use my current Adobe Air app (which is now unsupported), and I'd like to offer them this new app I'm building.

I've heared that Adobe Air's implementation of webkit is rather old and unstable.

Is there any good tools for wrapping a local browser (preferably webkit) and my app in an executable for cross-platform (PC) use?

Comment: [QtWebKit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtwebkit.html) is one option.

Comment: Seems like you have to write QML in QtWebKit? I just want to embed my existing html website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just seen this http://appjs.org/ and I'm glad to see that Alex's TideSDK sounds great also !

Adobe AIR can do what you want, but I won't support that solution : it's slow and not really crossplatform since they drop the support on Linux if I'm correct.

If someone happen to test the others, feedback is welcome !

Off topic: Moreover I've chosen not to trust Adobe for my technical choices anymore. We've waited Flash on mobile for years, they drop the idea. We've been waiting for optimization on Mac and Linux for years, but nobody cares. The new hype some months ago was expecting compilation to HTML5, it's just some buzzwords mixed together and some old sketchy alpha version as far as I know.

**EDIT**

AppJS has moved http://appjs.com/

**EDIT**

node-webkit seems to be definitely a must see now ! https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Comment: Dunno what appjs used to be, but the site seems to be taken over by a domain squatter.

Answer (score 0):

Read an article lately about this sdk: http://www.tidesdk.org/ . I haven't worked with it yet - so can't really say if it's worth trying and doing what you want.